# PHP/MySqli: Prepared MySqli statement with 2 tables and WHERE not returning data

Tags: php, xml, mysqli

i am trying to get data from 2 tables of my criminals database, and its not returning anything when I add a "AND criminal_name = 'FIDEL URBINA'" to get only the data per criminal.

This is my code and SQL statement right now,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT criminal_name, event_location FROM criminal_profile, criminal_locations 
    WHERE criminal_profile.criminal_id = criminal_locations.criminal_id");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($criminal_name, $event_location); //get data from statement
$stmt->store_result();


 if($formaat=='xml'){ //XML
            $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<criminals></criminals>');


            while($stmt->fetch()) // zolang er rijen zijn
            {
                // $criminal_name, Scriminal_pob en $event_location zijn gevuld
                //voeg element criminal_pob toe met naam criminal_pob, criminal_name en event_location:
                $info = $xml->addChild('criminal');
                $item = $info->addChild('criminal_name',$criminal_name);
                $item = $info->addChild('event_location',$event_location);
            }
            header('Content-type: text/xml'); //DIT WERKT NIET? cant send headers after they were sent

            // coderen als JSON:
            echo $xml->asXML();
        }
```

which repeats the criminals based on how many event locations they have, as shown in this image:

http://grabilla.com/05b0e-a271d885-dc45-47ad-a043-c92d832162bd.png

Anyone have a idea on why this is not returning data when I add a "AND criminal_name = 'FIDEL URBINA'" or anything like that? I also tried "AND criminal_name = 'F%'".

Comment: use this against your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  you have a syntax error and it would have told you so, IF that's your real code. Look at Stack's syntax highlighting. It's missing a quote. If that is in there, fix your question; it's throwing off syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh my bad, yeah it is in my actual code. I just updated my question.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @michi When I add a "AND" part in my statement, it stops returning data even though my screenshots data exists. Do you have an idea on what I am doing wrong? :)

Comment: delete that `XML` tag from your question to attract more users, your question is clearly about SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a matching problem for this you can try with `like` operatore  instead of `=`

```
"SELECT criminal_name, event_location FROM criminal_profile, criminal_locations 
WHERE criminal_profile.criminal_id = criminal_locations.criminal_id 
AND criminal_name LIKE '%FIDEL URBINA%");
```